# @Async does not work in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-async

I have a spring boot application and want to run a simple Async background task by using @async annotation , however , this does not seem to be working (no new threads are created and I wait until the sleep fininshes after each call to the function ..
*****my config class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

}
```

****My controller :**

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/testAsync")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testAsync() {

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        System.out.println("begin of test async dates is : " + new Date());

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            testClass.asyncMethod();
        }
        System.out.println("end of test async  dates is : " + new Date());

        return "end!";
    }
```

*****My TestClass where the Async method :**

```
@Service
public class TestClass {

    @Async
    public void asyncMethod() {
        System.out.println("Execute method asynchronously. in thread : "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("after sleep : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

****output after running the application :**

```
begin of test async dates is : Sat Jul 14 19:35:43 EET 2018
Execute method asynchronously. in thread : http-nio-8080-exec-1
after sleep : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Execute method asynchronously. in thread : http-nio-8080-exec-1
after sleep : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Execute method asynchronously. in thread : http-nio-8080-exec-1
after sleep : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Execute method asynchronously. in thread : http-nio-8080-exec-1
2018-07-14 19:36:22.299  INFO 3120 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
after sleep : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Execute method asynchronously. in thread : http-nio-8080-exec-1
after sleep : http-nio-8080-exec-1
end of test async  dates is : Sat Jul 14 19:36:33 EET 2018
```

****note:**
-I have tried annotating the TestClass with @Component it did not work
-I have tried adding an executor on both the application level and the method level but I am getting the same results.

please help me , I have spent 5 hours on this with no luck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Autowire the TestClass into the controller, make an instance member of the controller with type TestClass and give it the Autowire annotation.

When you instantiate it yourself Spring doesn't know about the Async annotations and calls to it will run in the calling thread.

Comment: thank you very much , it works like crazy! .thank you million times!